# iOS top navigationBar set title color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigationBar with `preferedLargesTitles = true`. I tried everything but i can't change from white the top navigationBar color.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the text colour of the bar button items using the tintColor property

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Testing"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .red
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`largeTitleTextAttributes` will do the job!

here is a sample:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]
```

Comment: nope, this only change the big one CONFIGURACIÓN from black to gray, no the top one.

Answer (score 0):

navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = .whatever do the trick!